Weak convergence and limit of empirical measure
Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be iid random variables, $X_1 \sim P$. Let $P_n$ be their corresponding empirical measure and $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and bounded function. Prove that random variables $\sqrt{n}(\int f dP_n -  \int f dP)$ converge weakly and find the limit.
My current proof I have constructed:

Observe that $\int fdP_n = \int \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(X_i)$ and $\int f dP = \mathbb{E}\left[f(X_1)\right]$. Hence $$\int f dP_n-\int f dP = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(X_i)-\mathbb{E}\left[f(X_1)\right].$$ We are interested in the expression $$\sqrt{n}\left(\int f dP_n -  \int f dP\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f(X_i)-\mathbb{E}\left[f(X_1)\right]\right).$$
Because $f(X_i)$ are iid random variables we can apply the CLT to the sequence ${f(X_i)}$ (the finite variance is implied by the boundness of the $f$). Thus $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f(X_i)-\mathbb{E}\left[f(X_1)\right]\right) \xrightarrow{d}N(0, \text{Var}\left[f(X_1)\right]).$$

This proof seems too primitive to me. Is my approach sensible or am I missing something? Also, does the weak convergence and the limit both imply from the CLT? Is there another way to show weak convergence?

I think your proof is fine. It's straightforward, not primitive.
